# How to get the servlet variable in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlet-3.0

I am trying to pass one variable from html form to servlet through script, and in servlet it will connect to DB and get two resultant variables.

Again i am using request dispatcher to forward the response back to html form but i am stuck in getting the variables to populate in the html form.

```html
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function showCustomer() {

    var kkk = document.getElementById("num").value;
    alert("this is mango1 "+kkk);

    var xmlhttp;

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            <!-- what should come here to get "set attributes value " -->

        }
    };

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "callserv1?num="+kkk, true); 
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action=""> 
Receipt no <input type="text" name="num" id="num"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showCustomer(num)" value ="call"/>
</form>
<p id="demo">Customer info will be listed here...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class callserv1 extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");   
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("This Example demonstrates, using Ajax request to Access Servlet ");
        String grnxx =  request.getParameter("num");
        String pono = null;
        String podt = null;

        out.println("i am in" +grnxx);  

        try
        {                 
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("connection db");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection estabilished"+con);

        //Input query to get PO and Itemlist for given GRn
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("query");

        while(rs.next()) {
            pono = rs.getString("doc");
            podt = rs.getString("dt"); 
            System.out.println("Pono:----   "+pono);
            System.out.println("Podt:----   "+podt);
        }

        con.close(); 
        System.out.println("DB Connection closed successfully");

        }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection error: "+e);
        }

        request.setAttribute("pono", pono);
        request.setAttribute("podt", podt);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use jQuery or some other JS utility that simplifies AJAX requests?

Comment: I didnt try that. Cant we get in above mentioned way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data from servlet to JSP (not HTML) using request forward and by setting data as attribute in request and then on JSP you can render those data to generate HTML

At Jsp side you can one of the below option to get attribute value.

- Scriptlets
- Expression Language

Comment: Thanks. Will try with new one.